# Disable color highlighting

Tags: gnus, display

**Background:**

I use `gnus` under `emacs -nw` (so this question is about text-based usage, not the GUI).  Depending on the value of the `$TERM` environment variable, `gnus` will, for example, highlight quoted text in articles, using different colors depending on the depth of quoting (the number of `>` characters at the beginning of each line).

I personally prefer plain black text on a white or light background. I usually run `emacs -nw` in a terminal emulator with color disabled; in that case it isn't an issue.

But for some ssh clients on mobile devices (particularly JuiceSSH on Android), there doesn't seem to be a way to disable color in the terminal emulator. And the default color scheme seems to assume I have a black background; since I use a white background, yellow text is essentially illegible.

One workaround I've found is to set `$TERM` to `vt100`, but that requires quitting and restarting emacs.  (I run it under GNU `screen`, so I commonly view the same Emacs session on different terminal emulators.)

**Finally, the question:**

Is there a command or configuration option in `emacs` or in `gnus` to tell it *not* to use color highlighting *without* quitting and restarting either `emacs` or `gnus`? A global configuration for `emacs` would be ideal, but something specific to `gnus` would do nicely.

If that's not practical, a decent backup solution would be a *straightforward* way to use a color scheme that's legible on a white background.

Comment: If you want no colors **always** I guess you could customize all the relevant faces. Probably a quite tedious chore. I guess it could be done programatically somehow...

Answer (score 3):

If all of the coloring is from `font-lock-mode` you can just turn off that mode.

You can also get the *effect* of removing all highlighting for a particular face by just customizing that face to be the same as face `default` (just inherit from face `default` and turn off all other face attributes besides inherit).

You can tell which face is used to highlight a given bit of text by putting the text cursor on that text and hitting `C-u C-x =`. The `*Help*` output tells you what faces are used at point (the cursor position).

Comment: `font-lock-mode` didn't help. As for "faces" I see multiple faces, including `gnus-header-name`, `gnus-header-from`, `gnus-header-subject`, `gnus-cite-1`, `gnus-cite-2`. I'm hoping for a single command that will disable all of them. If that's not possible, it would help to know *how* to customize a face (a reference to the documentation would probably suffice for that).

Comment: `M-x customize-face`. You can find it in the Emacs manual (`C-h r`), by using `i` to search the index. Pretty simple to find.

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of all the faces that are causing trouble (`M-x list-faces-display` is helpful). Wipe out the foreground/background attributes of those faces:

```
(cl-loop for face in '(gnus-header-name gnus-header-from gnus-header-subject …) do
     (set-face-attribute face nil :foreground nil :background nil))
```

If you want to wipe out the color from *all* faces, not only the gnus ones:

```
(cl-loop for face in (face-list) do
     (set-face-attribute face nil :foreground nil :background nil))
```

Comment: I ran into two problems with this, as described in the following questions: (1) https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55706/symbols-function-definition-is-void-cl-loop (2) https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55715/disable-coloring-of-text-in-operations-in-emacs-nw-during-operations-like-sear