# Symbol's function definition is void: cl-loop

Tags: init-file, cl-lib

I'm trying to turn off all colored text when using gnu emacs as `emacs -nw` on linux. [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19449/disable-color-highlighting) gives a snippet of code to use for this purpose:

```
(cl-loop for face in (face-list) do
     (set-face-attribute face nil :foreground nil :background nil))
```

However, when I put this in my .emacs file, I get this error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: cl-loop
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `cl-loop` is from `cl-macs.el`. Have you tried adding `(require 'cl-macs)` before using `cl-loop`?

Comment: @Aquaactress `cl-macs.el` is an internal subpackage of the package `cl-lib.el`. You should always `(require 'cl-lib)` or `(eval-when-compile (require 'cl-lib))` instead. See [`(cl) Organization`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Organization.html).

Comment: That works. Aquaactress or Basil, maybe that should be an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Aquaactress: I don't see that the manual section you point to says that `cl-macs.el` is "an internal subpackage" or that "you should always...". What it says is that you can just load `cl-lib.el` to get the macros (and a bunch of other stuff) autoloaded. If you only need a macro for byte-compilation I see no reason why you would necessarily want to load all that's in `cl-lib.el`. Of course there's nothing _wrong_ with loading `cl-lib.el`, and yes, it's generally what people do who want some of its functionality.

Comment: @Drew I think you meant to reference Basil. I was not the one who referenced that section.

Comment: @Aquaactress: Yes, sorry.

Comment: @Basil: Sorry, I meant to reply to you, not Aquaactress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct solution is to `(require 'cl-lib)` somewhere, but this is a trivial enough loop that Emacs comes with a macro specifically for it, without needing `cl-lib`:

```
(dolist (face (face-list))
  (set-face-attribute face nil :foreground nil :background nil))
```